# Finding row in Numpy array maximizing some function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What would be most elegant and efficient way to find the index of a row in a Numpy 2d array maximizing some function? In particular, I need to find the row with maximal dot product with a given vector. Say, I have

```
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]])
b = np.array([6, 5, 4])
```

Then the result should be `1` since `np.dot(a[1],b)` is greater than `np.dot(a[0],b)`.

Comment: What do you want to happen if there is more than one row which reaches the max?

Comment: @DSM either of them would be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

simply:

```
>>> np.argmax(a.dot(b))
1
```

[`np.argmax` docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html)

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method:

```
index = 0
value = 0
for index, entry in enumerate(a):
     if np.dot(entry,b)>value:
         index = index
         value = np.dot(entry,b)
```

`index` returns `1`